# Installing fonts on android

Tags: custom-roms, fonts, themes, lineageos

I used to have cyanogen os and it had this theme thing that I could change and install fonts to. But I upgraded to Lineage OS and it's not there anymore. I have some font apks but I dunno how to apply them after installation. Can I get some help?

Comment: Have you already consulted our [fonts tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fonts/info)? What from the offered solutions have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Cyanogen OS stops at Marshmallow and is deprecated; LineageOS 14.1 (along with CM14.1 before it), being fresh on Nougat, has yet to implement a theme engine, so you need to rely on 3rd-party solutions, which usually uses TTF/OTF format fonts. If you still want to use the fonts in the APKs, extract them from the APK package.